# Don't understand this code (assembly)

Tags: assembly, tasm

My assembly teacher didn't explain so well, so I don't know how to read a character and print the hex number from the ASCII table for that character

(for example a-> 61 A->41 0->30)

But I found this on stackoverflow

```
.model small
 .stack 100h
 .data

 texto db 'Enter: $'
 maximo db 9
 caractereslidos db 0
 string db 9 DUP (0)
 novalinha db 13,10,13,10,'$'
 hex1 db ?    ;FIRST  HEX DIGIT.
 hex2 db '  , $' ;SECOND HEXT DIGIT.

.code
proc convert       
  cmp DL, 9
  jbe its_a_digit ;JUMP IF ( DL <= 9 ).
;its_a_letter:  IF NO JUMP, STAYS HERE.
  add dl, 55 ;CONVERT TO LETTER.
  jmp finish  
its_a_digit:  
  add dl, 48 ;CONVERT TO DIGIT.
finish:
  ret
endp 

start:
  mov  AX, @data
  mov  DS, AX

  mov  AH, 9
  lea  DX, texto
  int  21h

  mov  AH, 0Ah
  lea  DX, maximo
  int  21h

  mov  AH, 9
  lea  DX, novalinha
  int  21h

  mov  CL, caractereslidos
  mov  ch, 0 ;CLEAR CH TO USE CX AS COUNTER.
  mov  SI, offset string

ciclo:         
;GET ONE CHARACTER FROM STRING.
  mov  DL, [SI] 
;ISOLATE LOWER 4 BITS IN CHARACTER.
  and  DL, 00001111b
  call convert ;CONVERT DL TO DIGIT OR LETTER.
  mov  hex2, dl ;SAVE CONVERTED CHARACTER TO DISPLAY LATER.
;GET THE SAME CHARACTER FROM STRING.
  mov  DL, [SI] 
;ISOLATE UPPER 4 BITS IN CHARACTER.
  shr  DL, 4 ;SHIFT DL 4 BITS TO THE RIGHT.
  call convert ;CONVERT DL TO DIGIT OR LETTER.
  mov  hex1, dl ;SAVE CONVERTED CHARACTER TO DISPLAY LATER.
;DISPLAY CONVERTED CHARACTER.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset hex1
  int  21h  

  inc  si ;NEXT CHARACTER TO CONVERT.
  loop ciclo

  mov AH,4Ch
  int 21h
end start
```

It works like a charm, but I don't know why. I would like to tell me what happens in the background. I am most interested in this parts : ciclo and convert

Comment: i know keywords but i m bad with DL SI etc . Is there a debbuger so i can see step by step what's in SI, DL and my variables?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  IDK about for 16bit code, but gdb works well for normal 32/64bit code.

Comment: @PeterCordes : _GDB_ can debug 16-bit code, but is very problematic since it has no concept of the CS:IP segment pair. There isn't to my knowledge a version of _GDB_ that runs in a 16-bit DOS environment. Since they are using _TASM_ (Turbo Assembler) I highly recommend that they use TD.EXE (Turbo debugger) which for its time was one of the best debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

Your program first gets an inputstring of max 9 characters through DOS function 0Ah.
Each character is represented by a byte sized value aka the **ASCII** value. Each byte consists of 8 bits.

The *ciclo* routine first takes the low 4 bits (`mov dl,[si]` `and dl,00001111h`) and then calls *convert* to change this small number in the range [0-15] into a character. This character is placed in the rightside position (2) within a preformated output string.

Next the *ciclo* routine takes the high 4 bits (`mov dl,[si]` `shr dl,4`) and then also calls *convert* to change this small number to a character. This character is placed in the leftside position (1) within the outputstring.

Now *ciclo* displays this outputstring and is then ready to process the next character from the inputstring (`inc si` `loop ciclo`).

In the procedure *convert* values in the range [0-9] are converted to characters "0", "1", ... "9" and values in the range [10-15] are converted to characters "A", "B", ... "F".

Example with an inputstring of "K":

```
ASCII of "K" = 4Bh --> value of low 4 bits = 11 --> character "B" in position 2
;                     value of high 4 bits =  4 --> character "4" in position 1
; --> display "4B , "
```